# How to optimize a cubes made world game?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, optimization, minecraft-modding, block-world

I'm making a cube-world-game like Minecraft. And to render it I've splitted it in 16x16x16 blocks regions (also known as chunks in mc) and then, on rendering, I take all the chunks in the rendering distance area and foreach of them I iterate all blocks and draw them.

It's so slow.

Then I tryed to remove hidden blocks and draw only visible faces of blocks. I made a VBO that store a face and then using model matrix I rotate it to make the other sides of the block. Finally I added a camera frustum test that checks if the block is visible from the camera.

I didn't code yet all these things, that's just a reasoning.

Are these optimization good or could I add something else?

P.S: I've seen that minecraft use a "display list" foreach chunk and not use a VBO for a face (I've didn't understand the code well since part of it is obfuscated) and each loop get just the rendering distance chunks and draw them using the display list stored. How's possible making a display list with all the shape of the chunk? There's another thing that does the same thing of the display list but it's not deprecated (I though VBO but I'm not sure)?

Comment: Don't do what Minecraft did.

Comment: Store all chunk vertices in one vbo per chunk? Why not?

Comment: @loryuta 1: It's terribly slow, changing VBO data takes a long time, 2.: There are way better alternatives, such as indexing.

Comment: Could you explain it better, please?

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you said above answers your question...

Split the world into "chunks," and only load these when the player is within a certain distance. Minecraft has that useful "Render Distance" setting. Yes, use VBOs. They can be optimized. Make sure to use shaders, rather than inline quads and alike. Make sure to cull faces than aren't visible. Assuming you're using OpenGL as you're renderer, I'd suggest building your project with version 3.0 minimum, 3.2 or 3.3 preferred, with compatibility profile or core profile. If you use the compatibility profile, you may notice a performance drop, as noted by Quentin.

Check out https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts for more information on that.

Comment: Is there maybe a way to encapsulate the data of a chunk in one single vbo and then render directly it?

Comment: You can! VBOs are basically arrays of data, storing your vertices, colors, etc... The purpose is to store your data before rendering, so the application doesn't have to generate your stuff each frame. You're going to want to use VAOs too, which essentially wrap all your VBOs, so you don't have to manage individual ones. This is a huge performance boost.

Comment: Two great resources: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tutorial2:_VAOs,_VBOs,_Vertex_and_Fragment_Shaders_(C_/_SDL) (you should read the whole wiki) and http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/vertexbuffers.html

Comment: Re: "core backwards capabilities" -- It's not clear whether you mean the core profile or the compatibility profile.

Comment: @Quentin Fixed the typo, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Note that the compatibility profile can have negative performance effects, since it essentially has to emulate the older APIs on top of the newer one.

Comment: Like Balint said, check out the Minecraft source. http://www.modcoderpack.com/website/ is a set of tools to decompile and deobfuscate the Minecraft executables. Be aware that while this is commonly used for mod development, even existing as a sub forum on the Minecraft forums, it is not officially supported, and technically breaks the license. Also, the Minecraft source is proprietary, so you can't copy anything. But feel free to view, analyze, and learn from it using MCP. If this answer helped you, please check it off! Thank you very much